# How to frame Linq Query for this condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

My Table fileds and values:

**IdFavorite**: 1,2,3,4,5

**FavoriteName**: Fav1, Fav2, Fav3, Fav4, Fav5

**UserId**: 1, 3, 3, 4, 3

**PublicFavorite**: 0, 1, 0, 1, 0

As of now I used following Linq query to get the list of **Favorite Names** basd on the **User ID**

```
public IList<ReportFavorite> GetReportFavorites(int userId)
{
    return _reportFavoriteRepository.GetMany(x => x.UserId == userId).ToList();
}
```

Now, the condition is as above **plus**, I need to get all the **Favorite Names** that has **PublicFavorite** is 1. I need the Linq query according to this condition. Thanks.

For eg: If My **User Id** is 3, then I should get the **Favorite Names** as **Fav2**, **Fav3**, **Fav5** and also **Fav4**(since **PublicFavorite** is 1)

Comment: `GetMany(x => x.UserId == userId || x.PublicFavorite == 1)` -- what's bothering you exactly?

Comment: operator == cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int' msg is displayed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code as per Jon's comment. It is working fine as expected.

```
GetMany(x => x.UserId == userId || x.PublicFavorite == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var res =
    from item in _reportFavoriteRepository
    where item.UserId == userId || item.PublicFavorite == publicFavorite
    select item.FavoriteName;
```